# How can I select an unpaired tag in XML using XPATH depending on what is included in the preceding string?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am racking my brain trying to figure out how to use XPATH to select the following linebreak tags in XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Structure>
 <Branch>
  <content>
   <par>
    Line 1: This is some text with a space after the period. <linebreak/>
    Line 2: This is some text with no space after the period.<linebreak/>
    Line 3: This text doesn't end in a period and must also be handled differently<linebreak/>
    Line 4: This text doesn't matter.
   </par>
  </content>
 </Branch>
</Structure>
```

What I nee are XPATH statements that will select the linebreak tags depending on what comes in the preceding string (either a period and no space, a period with space, or no period and no space).

Basically, I need to handle these tags differently in our translation software. I've tried things like  `//*[ends-with(.,'.')]/following-sibling::linebreak[position() < 3]` and  `//par[ends-with(text(), ' .')] /linebreak` but unfortunately to know avail. I would be very grateful for some help in finding XPATHs that match Lines 1-3.

(Note that the XML notation above is simply for good readability; assume that everything is on one line.)

Comment: So you will only need to extract line 1 to 3?

Comment: Yes, I need to actually select the linebreak tags, but separately (need an Xpath for the linebreak terminating line 1, one for line 2 and one for line 3).

Comment: so you need 3 xpaths? why not use index?

Comment: Can your provide an example of doing so? Am unfamiliar with this.

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the first two `<linebreak />`s, you can use the following XPath-2.0 expression

```
//content/par/linebreak[ends-with(normalize-space(preceding::text()[1]),'.')]
```

This matches the first two.
To handle the third one differently, you can negate the predicate

```
//content/par/linebreak[not(ends-with(preceding::text()[1],'.')) and not(ends-with(preceding::text()[1],' '))]
```

You can also apply DeMorgan on this one to simplify it

```
//content/par/linebreak[not(ends-with(preceding::text()[1],'.') or ends-with(preceding::text()[1],' '))]/preceding::text()[1]
```

The result is the same, the third `<linebreak />`.
To check whether the string before ends with a dot followed by a space, do

```
//content/par/linebreak[ends-with(preceding::text()[1],'. ')]
```

Comment: Tested and working as you specify! :D Is there any way to make that final distinction in lines 1 and 2 - that there is a space following the period but before the linebreak tag in line 1?

Comment: Do you mean that it ends with `. `?

Comment: Yes. I think this is working:
`Line 1: //content/par/linebreak[ends-with(preceding::text()[1],'. ')]`
`Line 2: //content/par/linebreak[ends-with(preceding::text()[1],'.')]`
`Line 3: //content/par/linebreak[not(ends-with(preceding::text()[1],'.')) and not(ends-with(preceding::text()[1],' '))]`

basically just removed the normalize-space.

Answer (score 0):

getting `first line`

```
//Structure/Branch/content/par/linebreak[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[1]
```

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean. This would probably work in this concrete case, but these are simply example sentences. The linebreaks will occur randomly in the XML file, some with periods (and spaces) and some without.